# Python hide label and button by event

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I wnat to hide my label and button when someone is pushing a button but i have the problem in my code that i dont can acces the label variable and that i dont know how to hide maybe it works with this code?:

```
setStyleSheet("display: none;")
```

And here is my code that doesnt work whe i push the button the python programm say no respond

```
   import sys
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
    from PyQt5 import QtGui
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

    class WindowInhalt(QWidget):
        def label(self):
            label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            label1.setText("Überschrift mit namen des text adventure")
            label1.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
            label1.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
            label1.move(350, 50)

            label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            label2.setText("Spielen")
            label2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
            label2.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
            label2.move(450, 120)
            label2.mousePressEvent = self.spielen

            label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            label3.setText("Settings")
            label3.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
            label3.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
            label3.move(450, 200)
            label3.mousePressEvent = self.settings

            label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            label4.setText("Credits")
            label4.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
            label4.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
            label4.move(450, 280)
            label4.mousePressEvent = self.credits

        def Button(self):
            QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
            button = QPushButton("Spiel beenden", self)
            button.setGeometry(50, 50, 150, 50)
            button.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
            button.move(820, 420)
            button.setToolTip("<b>Button lel</b>")
            button.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
            button.clicked.connect(self.gedruekt)
            button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")


    class Window(WindowInhalt):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.initMe()

        def initMe(self):
            WindowInhalt.Button(self)
            WindowInhalt.label(self)
            self.setGeometry(50,50,1000,500)
            self.setWindowTitle("Gui lalal einhorn")
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("cookie.png"))
            self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")
            self.move(500, 250)
            self.show()

        def spielen(self, event,):
            print("spielen")
            WindowInhalt.label.label2.setStyleSheet("display:none;")
#here i want to hide the label


        def settings(self, event):
            print("settings")

        def credits(self, event):
            print("credits")

        def gedruekt(self, event):
            print("Er hats getan ;(")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = Window()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    else:
        print("Gui not created, because script used at liabary")
```

maybe somone can help me.

**EDIT1:** 
when i do it so

```
 def spielen(self, event,):
        print("spielen")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label1.hide()
```

than i get in the console the message spielen but the label is still there
when i do it so:

```
def spielen(self, event,):
    print("spielen")
    self.label1.hide()
```

than the programm crasht

**EDIT2:**
For anyone who is instredtef above the right code her he is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class WindowInhalt(QWidget):
    def label(self):
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label1.setText("Überschrift mit namen des text adventure")
        self.label1.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        self.label1.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        self.label1.move(350, 50)
        self.label1.show()

        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("Spielen")
        self.label2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        self.label2.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        self.label2.move(450, 120)
        self.label2.mousePressEvent = self.spielen
        self.label2.show()

        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label3.setText("Settings")
        self.label3.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        self.label3.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        self.label3.move(450, 200)
        self.label3.mousePressEvent = self.settings
        self.label3.show()

        self.label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label4.setText("Credits")
        self.label4.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        self.label4.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        self.label4.move(450, 280)
        self.label4.mousePressEvent = self.credits
        self.label4.show()

    def button(self):
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
        self.button = QPushButton("Spiel beenden", self)
        self.button.setGeometry(50, 50, 150, 50)
        self.button.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        self.button.move(820, 420)
        self.button.setToolTip("<b>Button lel</b>")
        self.button.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.gedruekt)
        self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.button.show()


class Window(WindowInhalt):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initMe()

    def initMe(self):
        self.label()
        self.button()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,1000,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Gui lalal einhorn")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("cookie.png"))
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")
        self.move(500, 250)
        self.show()

    def spielen(self, event,):
        print("spielen")
        self.label1.hide()

    def settings(self, event):
        print("settings")

    def credits(self, event):
        print("credits")

    def gedruekt(self, event):
        print("Er hats getan ;(")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
else:
    print("Gui not created, because script used at liabary")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to refer to an object you've created inside a class, you need to declare it as an attribute of this class, with `self.labelX`:

```
self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
```

Then in any method of this class, you can easily call this attribute:

```
self.label1.hide()
```

or elsewhere in the code

```
window_inhalt_instance.label1.hide()
```

---

**EDIT :** 
I focused on how you're instantiating the class, you need to change some parts here too:

The labels are not hidden because they are created with `WindowInhalt.label(self)`

As your class Window inherits from WindowInhalt, you can called directly

```
 self.label()  # in initme(), same for the buttons
```

But you need to change every labels declaration in WindowInhalt, by adding self

Comment: yeah now it works thank you very much i am still a beginner

Comment: @Yuto No prob, just think about when you create a class, it's a model to create object, don't use this model directly as `WindowInhalt.label(self)`, but create instance instead, like you did with `w = Window()`.

Comment: yeah i try it thank you.I try to become better in set instance instead models directly ^^